# jQuery Hover Click Pagination

Tags: jquery, hover, click

I'm trying to trigger pagination button from "mouse click" to "mouse hover". This is what I've tried

```
jQuery('.esg-pagination-button').hover(function(){  
    jQuery(this).trigger('click');  
});
```

But the code above only trigger once.

Comment: *"only trigger once"* what do you mean ?

Comment: I've applied the code on the test page and the button click only triggered once when I hover over the pagination at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt find where is the code to handler the "trigger" event, but in some way it seems that the event is unbinded.

If you bind the event "mouseenter" (equivalent to hover function) through "live" it works correctly

```js
jQuery('.esg-pagination-button').live('mouseenter', function(){  
    jQuery(this).trigger('click');  
});
```